# ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'libmy_json_udf.so'

Tags: php, mysql

Installing MySQL JSON UDFs

**Step 1:**
mysql> show variables like 'plugin_dir';

+--------------------+--------------------------+

| Variable_name | Value                    |

+--------------------+--------------------------+

| plugin_dir   | /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/ |

+--------------------+--------------------------+

**Step 2:** Bellow command run on Linux/ Vagrant

**$ wget [http://downloads.mysql.com/snapshots/pb/mysql-json-udfs-0.3.0/mysql-json-udfs-0.3.0-labs-json-udfs-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz](http://downloads.mysql.com/snapshots/pb/mysql-json-udfs-0.3.0/mysql-json-udfs-0.3.0-labs-json-udfs-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz__)**

**$ tar xvf mysql-json-udfs-0.3.0-labs-json-udfs-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64.tar.gz**

**$ cp -i mysql-json-udfs-0.3.0-labs-json-udfs-linux-glibc2.5-x86_64/libmy_json_udf.so /usr/lib64/mysql/plugin/.**

**Step 3:**
mysql> create function json_extract returns string soname 'libmy_json_udf.so';

It will gives error--

**ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'libmy_json_udf.so'**

How to resolve this issue?

I want result like as folows,

mysql> select json_extract('{"a":1,"b":2}','b');

+-----------------------------------+

| json_extract('{"a":1,"b":2}','b') |

+-----------------------------------+

| 2                                 |

+-----------------------------------+

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71265

As suggested in MySQL bug tracker, a workaround is to symlink the libraries

```
root:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ln -s libpcreposix.so libpcreposix.so.0
root:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ln -s libpcre.so libpcre.so.0
```

Another workaround is to use cmake option **WITH_PCRE=bundled**

Comment: /x86_64-linux-gnu this directory is not available in /usr/lib. But all existing symblinks are available in /usr/lib so i have created above symblinks in /usr/lib but still its not working.

Not getting this line--->Another workaround is to use cmake option WITH_PCRE=bundled

Comment: btw, did you reload the mysql configuration after putting the file?